# Issues with clearfix

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I have created a html and can be found http://temp87.web44.net/temp.html.
Problem what i'm facing is there is a gray strip at the bottom of page after footer and the page is not occupying 100% of browser.

[image]

CSS which is causing the issue..

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";   //If this is commented out the page fits in perfectly, but the background of <div>storyWrapper clearfix</div> goes off.
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Problem 2: Also i want the height of

```
<div class="detailsContent"/>
```

to fit automatically according to the resolution of the screen. 
Right now computed height is always 619px and in large monitors the whole page occupies only 75% of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `"."` from `content`. write like this:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thank you sandeep it worked :) Also my page is occupying only half of the screen and in bigger resolutions it looks really odd..any help on this..

Comment: For you can use sticky footer technique http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: but i'm not using a sticky footer in this page but instead footer scroll's down with the page.

Comment: because you page height is not much. So,you can do two things First give body background the same color as footer or second you can use sticky footer technique.